# "ENOENT: no such file or directory in monorepo with yarn workspaces

Tags: node.js, angular, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have two repositories which independent (not in a monorepo) work like a charm (building & testing). However, as soon as I place them in a monorepo with yarn workspaces it doesn't work any more.

Let me explain: I have an angular and a node/typescript repository. Inside the Monorepo, when I run `yarn test`, the tests inside my node/typescript project still work, but the angular ones give Schema validation failed with the following errors:

[image]

So, as we know with `yarn workspaces` all node_modules are hoisted to the root, so I decided to turn hoisting off

```
...
"workspaces": {
    "packages": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
        "**/ui",
        "**/ui/**",
        "**/core",
        "**/core/**"
    ]
},
...
```

I removed all `node_modules` and tried to run `yarn` again. However, this time the installation of packages already fails with the following message:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat....rimraf
```

[image]

I found this open [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4563) which is probably the same, but does not provide a workaround. So if someone knows a way to workaround this I would really like to know?! Cheers

For more details you can checkout the repo [here](https://github.com/scaljeri/flow-based-programming)

Comment: I don't think hoisting is causing your Jest problems, but with the information provided so far I'm not able to identify exactly what's going on. First question, about `rimraf`, is it a package dependency or a root monorepo dependency? Also, you can make sure all your sub `package.json` files have a `main` entry pointing to a valid js file.

Comment: I'm not using rimraf, I think it is a dependency of a dependency. I'll update my post and list my configuration files at the bottom

Comment: Maybe easier to link directly to the repo, its an opensource project :) You can find it [here](https://github.com/scaljeri/flow-based-programming)

Comment: Great, you can use the `yarn why rimraf` command at the monorepo root to track where it is being used. About the repository, that's a known limitation. Versioning won't properly with Yarn + Lerna + Git Repositories, but it's manageable. With these further info, I'll be able to address properly inside an answer.

Comment: Ok, now I can see where rimraf is used and I see the different versions. So, what I did was, in my main package.json I defined `rimraf` (lowest version). Not sure if this forces the package to use one version. What exactly can you do about this problem?

Comment: The best approach is to set it in the root devDependencies, but also set the selective resolution -> https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/. That way the Yarn will honor your explicit version.

Comment: I upgraded to yarn2 (without PnP enabled) and the problem went away

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but I run into a very similar issue, so, here's a possible solution just in case it could be helpful to anyone.

> TL;DR - build your packages & try again

In my case the problem was that I wasn't able to install any new dependencies with `yarn` because of the `ENOENT`.
It turned out to be that I needed to build my packages first because otherwise `yarn` would discover that symlinks that connect my packages are broken & will not proceed with the installation.

Interestingly enough, the project I was trying to add new dependencies into was **not** dependent on any other package in the monorepo, but it didn't matter & `yarn` was failing anyway.